# I want to send JS POST requests using Selenium, but new XMLHttprequests in JS is not defind

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I have been googling and reading MDN, and trying different things, and still can not get it to work.Is anyone able to help with this?Why does it cause such a problem?

```
js = '''
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'https://www.ti.com.cn/occservices/v2/ti/addtocart', false);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
xhr.send('{"cartRequestList":[{"packageOption":null,"opnId":"%s","quantity":"%d","tiAddtoCartSource":"store-pdp","dienCode":"","year":"","week":"","batchCode":"","pcrCode":"","sparam":""}],"currency":"CNY"}');
return xhr.response;''' % (product['opn'], product['num'])
js = js.replace(" ", "").replace("\n", "")
resp = driver.execute_script(js)
return resp
```

Comment: You have a very peculiar first line. It has 3 apostrophes (single quotes) so the next line is going to look like it's part of a string. Try "'" (that's double quotes, single quote, double quotes) though I don't undertand why js would want a single quote initially.

Comment: This one is hit enter while pasting, It's a piece of JS.so it shouldn't matter.

Comment: What error you get when you run it? This API is giving 403 forbidden error when hit in postman.

Comment: When I use selenium.execute_script(), it prompts this error: new XMLHttpRequest() is not defind。I want to know why this results

Comment: I am getting javascript error: Invalid or unexpected token, no XMLHTTPRequest not defined error

Comment: Execute this:  js = '''

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'https://www.ti.com.cn/occservices/v2/ti/addtocart', false);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');

xhr.send('"cartRequestList": [{"packageOption": null,"opnId": "%s","quantity": "%d","tiAddtoCartSource": "store-pdp",
"dienCode": "","year": "","week": "","batchCode": "","pcrCode": "","sparam": ""}],"currency": "CNY" }' ); 

return xhr.response; 

'''

result = driver.execute_script(js);
print(result);

Comment: Ok, I'll try again

Comment: thanks. The problem has been solved. I comment out the replace() line and it works